# Make assembly function exception safe

Tags: c++, exception, assembly

My program is written in C++. The program generates assembly functions at runtime (with asmjit library). The assembly functions may call other C++ functions which my throw exceptions.

My question is how to make C++ exception safely propagate through my function. The platform is x86_64/Linux.

I did some test:

C++ file:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void asm_function();

extern "C" void throws_exception() {
    throw std::runtime_error("exception incoming.");
}


int main() {
    try {
        asm_function();
        std::cout << "Whoops, asm_function returned unexpectedly\n";
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Got exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the assembly function is like this:

```
.global asm_function
asm_function:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    call throws_exception
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

The program crashes, with error message like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  exception incoming.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If the assembly function is as simple as a "jmp" instruction, the test function works, but my program cannot be so simple.

Comment: What OS / ABI / calling convention are you targeting?  For ELF executable on Linux at least, you use `.cfi` directives (Call Frame Information) to create stack-unwind metadata.  Look at compiler output for example.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to insert unwind information at runtime, which is OS specific. For example on Windows there is `RtlAddFunctionTable()` function.

Comment: @Petr Any idea how to add unwind information for x86_64 Linux ?

Comment: There is an older gist:

https://gist.github.com/dpjudas/925d5c4ffef90bd8114be3b465069fff

I know it's not an answer, but maybe you would find that useful. It's not a one-liner to add such support, and because of complexity and OS differences this was not added to asmjit so far.